# jBPM editing different tools

Tags: jbpm

I am new to jBpm, and a little bit confused about the different editing tools for creating processes.
I was reading some jboss documentation and also the e-book "jbpm5 Developer Guide", but still not clear, after I deploy the jbpm installation (by runnning ant start.demo) I can:

1. create a new process from the web portal at url http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console
2. Create a new process from the Eclipse that is opened
3. according to the documentation there should be also drools-guvnor editor (I could not open it. when I press http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor nothing is opened).
4. according to the documentation there should be also other tools.

WELL, as I said, totally confused... what should be my starting point??

Answer (score 2):

The question is ambiguous, but this is my attempt to answer it:

1. Install the BPM Suite.
2. Use the Console/Workbench in order to create a new Business Process or another kind of business object that you need. I'll assume that you need a Process.
3. Design the process, save and commit it to the repo.
4. Define what to do with the Business Process and from where:

   1. Use Java (Eclipse?)
   2. REST API (Java or another programming language)
5. Execute the calls to use the designed Business Process.

I'm just guessing here... but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to state in your question which version are you using, I will assume that you are using version 5 if you are reading the version of the book.